# Execute puppet file in a remote server via ssh

Tags: ruby, ssh, provisioning, puppet

Is it possible to execute a puppet in a remote server using SSH?
I don't want to have to install ruby on the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, only Puppet can interpret Puppet files. I think it is easier to install Puppet's dependencies (including Ruby) than finding/developing a Puppet replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet (and facter) needs to be able to inspect the filesystem, process tables and other kernel tables (to mention just a few things) of the remote server.  To to this, it has to be executed **on** the remote server.  ssh does not offer a way to run a command on host A in such a way that it executes on host B with access to host B's resources; it does offer a way to execute a program installed on host B from host A, but that is not what you want.

Puppet comes with an overhead (the space required to install it and its dependencies, plus the memory and CPU time that it consumes); if you don't like the overhead, don't use Puppet.

Note: if it *were* possible to do what you want, then you'd have saved a small amount of space on host B but would have three new problems:

1. Significant increase of the load on your puppetmaster, if it has do to *all* the work.
2. Still a lot of work on the remote server, as it provides access to the resources
3. Large increase in network traffic.